# Execute (run) exec() function on Debian 9 server with root permissions using php file

Tags: php, debian, php-5.6, apache2.4

Good time forum users. 
Please tell me what could be the problem and any way how to fix it. 
I will be sincerely grateful if you help me with this question. 
There is a server with `root` rights (only one user in the system) with settings out of the box (default):

`Debian GNU/Linux 9`
`Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)`
`PHP 5.6.40-1+0~20190111135530.9+stretch~1.gbp5f42c9 (cli)`
`Asterisk 13.23.1`

There was a difficulty to execute the exec function, shell_exec, in a php file ... (these functions are not prohibited.) I understand that when you run a php file lacks rights, because it is not root.

```
public static function restartAsterisk() {

        //exec("reboot", $top, $error);
        exec("systemctl reload asterisk", $top, $error); // !!!! PROBLEMS!!!! Absolute path no helped
        if (!$error) {
            //Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Все сервисы перезапустились удачно!');
        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('danger', 'Asterisks не может быть перезапущен!');
        }
    }
```

I remember that I made these functions run from a php file, but after `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` - everything does not work again.
It seems to me that the problem is possible with the file `/etc/sudoers`, but after repeated recovery, I understand that the problem may be different...
In case of sudories file

**testing:**

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
// echo exec('systemctl reload asterisk', $output, $return_val);
echo exec('sudo systemctl reload asterisk', $output, $return_val);
if($return_val !== 0) {
    echo '<br />Error<br />';
    print_r($output);   
    print_r($return_val);   
}
```

**Output:**

```
www-data
Error
Array ( ) 1
```

`/etc/php/5.6/cli`

```
[PHP]
engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
asp_tags = Off
precision = 14
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = 17
disable_functions =
disable_classes =
zend.enable_gc = On
expose_php = On
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = -1
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = On
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 8M
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On
[Date]
[filter]
[iconv]
[intl]
[sqlite3]
[Pcre]
[Pdo]
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
[Phar]
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = On
[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent = 1
ibase.max_persistent = -1
ibase.max_links = -1
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"
[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile = On
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.cache_size = 2000
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off
[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off
[OCI8]
[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent = On
sybct.max_persistent = -1
sybct.max_links = -1
sybct.min_server_severity = 10
sybct.min_client_severity = 10
[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0
[browscap]
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
<input> field with the info which is otherwise appended
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatibility_mode = Off
mssql.secure_connection = Off
[Assertion]
[COM]
[mbstring]
[gd]
[exif]
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
[sysvshm]
[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1
[mcrypt]
[dba]
[opcache]
[curl]
[openssl]
```

Comment: You aren't really using `sudo` there. So you meant that the webserver or php process runs as root already? Process output and php/fpm.ini for proof please. Else [How can I debug exec() problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12199353)

Comment: Is there any error message involved?

Comment: Nico Haase, edited question (added echo). result was an empty array (example and output wrote)

Comment: mario, i updated question) thanks for continue helping

Comment: answer: addition `reboot www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` into fille `/etc/sudoers`